# Add extra headers to all requests (Angular to Tomcat)

Tags: angularjs, tomcat, http-headers

I have an **Angular app** running on port **3000**. And my **Rest server** is running on port **8080**.

I want to add an extra header to all requests made to the rest server.

So, here is the `web.xml` config file of the rest server:

```
<filter>

    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>

    <!-- With or without this, it doesn't work -->
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
        <param-value>http://localhost:3000</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>Location</param-value>
    </init-param>

</filter>
```

When I add this in my interceptor.js:

```
config.headers["x-rest-version"] = "2.0.0"; // version dynamically generated
```

The server returns 403 :

```
# Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.
```

[image]

[image]

When I remove the line in the javascript file, the request is successfully done.

[image]

Comment: I guess, the error sames to be on preflight request (OPTIONS), isn't it?
May you need to add `x-rest-version` to the `cors.allowed.headers`?

Comment: Wow, amazing! That's funny because I already played around this param according to tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html but never understood I had to put `x-rest-version` in the `param-value` node. It's working now.

Comment: Happy to help, I gonna post a response to let this question answered with a little more of detail about the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP servers use to check HTTP headers and you are trying to pass the header `x-rest-version` and it is not white-listed on your config.

Add `x-rest-version` to the `cors.allowed.headers`.

```
...
<init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
    <param-value>x-rest-version,Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers</param-value>
</init-param>
...
```